# Is this quantity upper bounded?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

For $n$ a large enough given positive composite integer, let $a_{n}:=\pi(\sqrt{2n-3})$ with $\pi$ the prime counting function. Let also $P_{k}$ denote the product of the first $k$ primes.

Define $A(n):=\frac{\log P_{a_{n}}^{2/a_{n}}}{\log\log n}$.

Is $A(n)$ upper bounded? If yes, what is its supremum?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I made a quick estimation that $P_{k}\approx k^{k(1+o(1))}$ from the PNT. On the other hand $a_{n}\sim 2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{n}/\log n$ so one should get something like $2\log a_{n}/\log\log n$ but that's highly non rigorous.

Comment: You can write $P_{a_n} = \prod\limits_{p \leqslant \sqrt{2n-3}} p$, thus your numerator is $$\frac{2 \vartheta(\sqrt{2n-3})}{\pi(\sqrt{2n-3})} \sim 2\log \sqrt{2n-3} = \log (2n-3)$$ by the PNT.

Comment: Ok, so it's not bounded.